# How to understand this notation on Fourier transformation?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

For a function $f$, recall the Fourier trnasformation $\widehat{f}(u)=\int_R e^{iux}f(x)dx$ (Maybe someone call it Fourier inversion, but it doesn't matter). Now let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator from $L^2(R, dx)$ into itself. How to understand the notation $\widehat{\psi}(T)$, where $\psi$ is in the Schwart space?

Thanks!

Comment: What about substituting $T$ for $x$ and $\psi$ for $f$? Note that $e^{ixT}$ is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is a Borel function on $\mathbb{R}$, then you can define $F(T)$ using the spectral theorem. If $T$ has the spectral representation
$$
                    Tf = \int \lambda dE(\lambda)f,
$$
then
$$
                   F(T)f = \int F(\lambda)dE(\lambda)f.
$$
The domain of $F(T)$ consists of all $f$ for which
$$
                       \int |F(\lambda)|^{2}d\|E(\lambda)f\|^{2} < \infty.
$$
For your case, you want $\hat{\psi}(T)$. The function $\hat{\psi}$ is particularly well-behaved because $\psi$ is well-behaved. That should lead to a bounded operator.

Comment: Dear TrialandError, thank you very much!

Comment: @user240316 : You're welcome.